# django framework, how to deploy the project about blog demo?

Tags: python, django

there is console on under picture

[image]

The project is django demo from github, I don't know where modify database username and database password. This is sqlite3.

This is github link: https://github.com/MoreYoungGavin/my_blog

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, copy and paste the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try delete in your **settings.py** file the lines

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + [
'django.core.context_processors.request',
 ]
BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_SIDEBAR_MENU = True
```

(as they are [only work for django 1.7](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrap/django-admin-bootstrap#install) and I suppose you have a newer version of Django)
and restart the development server.